# How can I get information about a non-web client connecting to my socket with socket.io

Tags: node.js, tcp, socket.io

I have a hospital lab machine (Sysmex’s X-500i haematology analyser) connected to the network and configured to send data to a certain address and port. A simple node.js script listens to connections made to that address and port.

I can see that connections are being made when the analyser is being used but I cannot extract the message that is being sent. Since the analyser is not a web client I cannot write client code to grab the data using HTML or otherwise.

Is there a way in which, upon connection with client devices that are not web based, socket.io can process incoming messages. Or if I am completely off course, is there a better way to implement this?

Below is my server side code

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');

var app = express();

var server = app.listen(8085, function(){
    console.log("Listening to requests on port 8085");
});

app.use(express.static('public'))

var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    console.log('Connection made successfully - ', socket.id)

});
```

Below is code I have written to simply establish connection

```
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.8.100:8085/');
```

Comment: If the analyser is not sending web (HTTP) requests then socket.io and express will not know how to handle the incoming traffic.  It sounds like you need to write a plain TCP server to accept connections and read data directly from them.  From Node's built-in `net` module use `net.createServer()` and then tell the server to `listen()` on port 8085. The callback you give to `createServer` will fire for each new connection. In that callback you can define handlers for events on the `socket` that represents the connection. You'll want to handle at least the `data` and `close` events.

Comment: @ottomeister thanks for responding. After struggling a bit with this, I decided to go with a piece of software called Mirth Connect which does much of the heavy lifting. I will however try this out in case I need to drop a level down in future integrations.